# Get a cursor from Realm GraphQL for implementing pagination

Tags: pagination, graphql, realm

Realm offers a great GraphQL API for data fetching and everything was good until I run into pagination. I successufully implemented Offset-based pagination (https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/pagination/), but faced some problems with Cursor-based pagination. Currently, Realm's GraphQL schema does not contain *cursor, edges, nodes, pageInfo* etc. Is there any way to force Realm generate such things?